# Understanding this SQL Syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, heidisql

```
load data infile 'D:\\diiet\\subir\\a.txt'
Into table reporte_dts_empresa_2015_sut CHARACTER SET latin1
fields terminated by '\t'
```

Why do I have to do this step?

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

I am new on sql, I'm trying to create a table whith excel data

i already done it, but im not sure how.

Answer (score 2):

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

This options tells MySQL that the lines in your input files are terminated with a sequence of carriage return and new line. This is important since different conventions exists for end of lines (notably, Windows and Linux differ).

```
IGNORE 1 LINES
```

With this option, the first line of input is skipped (MySQL will not attempt to inserted it in the table). This is typically useful if your file contains a header row.

You might want to have a look at [the MySQL documentation of the `LOAD DATA` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html).

Comment: Welcome @AndreaSilva! If my answer properly responded to your question, please accept it by clicking the green check sign... Thanks!